# How to implement Drill-Across in an SSAS Cube

Tags: ssas, multidimensional-array

I have a pretty good idea how to model drill-across in a relational plattform. It's the two-phased process described by Kimball, where you first run your query on each individual fact table and then apply a FULL OUTER JOIN to combine the results.

I don't know though how to model this in a multidimensional SSAS world. Can someone describe the process or point me to some Best Practise examples?

Thanks lots.

Answer (score 0):

While you can definitely define a **drillthrough** action at the cube level for each each measure group...I don't think it is possible define a **drillacross** action from one measure/measuregroup to another at the cube level.

That said, this [custom drillacross] is certainly possible at the application level.  For example, you can define a drill action on cells in an SSRS report that executes a subreport pulling in data via a parameterized MDX source query.  Here's [an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2012/03/19/implementing-mdx-drillthrough-in-ssrs.aspx) of this.